# Sum of even Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: ruby

Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

```
a    = [1,2]
upto = 4_000_000

while a[-2] + a[-1] < upto
  a << a[-2] + a[-1]
end

sum  = 0
a.each { |x| sum += x if x.even? }

puts "The result is #{sum}"
```

How does this work? What is `a[-2]`? What does that even mean? *The negative second index of a* **or** *a minus 2*? Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is negative index. `a[-1]` and `a[-2]` are the last two elements of the array `a`.

Comment: Let me understand this `a = [10,20,30,40]` then `a[-2]` equals 30 ?

Comment: Correct, and since this is Ruby, you can check it yourself in the `irb`

Comment: Yes I did check it in irb! ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you watch closely, you'll see the following sequence:

1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 ...

The formula for mapping the Fibonacci sequence is:

[image]

And you only want the sum of the **even** numbers such as:

1 1 **2** 3 5 **8** 13 21 **34** 55 89 **144** ...

So you can map a new formula such as:

[image]

And you will obtain the following sequence:

2 8 34 144 ...

Code example (Go):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fibonacci() func() int {
    first, second := 0, 2
    return func() int {
        ret := first
        first, second = second, first+(4*second)
        return ret
    }
}

func main() {
    sum := 0
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; sum < 4000000; i++ {
        sum += f()
    }
    fmt.Println(sum)
}
```

In that case you will not need the if conditionals.

Hope that helped you! Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

```
def fibonacci(array)
new_fibs = []
new_fibs << array[0]
new_fibs << array[1]
sum = 0
i = 0
while new_fibs.last < 4_000_000
    sum = new_fibs[i] + new_fibs[i+1]
    new_fibs << sum
    i += 1
end


total_even = 0
new_fibs.each do |fibs|
    if fibs%2 == 0
        total_even = total_even + fibs
    end
end
p total_even
end

fibonacci([1,2])
```

Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.